# ReactJS: wait until state is filled before making next call

Tags: reactjs

I have quite a big function that retrieves a bunch of information about Spotify playlists. Because the data is paginated I have a to make a couple of calls and append data to the state recursively. After that's done, I want to pass the state along with a POST request to another endpoint, to make some calculations. The returned values are then stored in state as well.

```
const fetchPlaylist = (playlistId) => {

    showLoading()

    setTitles([])
    setArtists([])
    setFeatures([])
    setTSNEfeatures([])
    setIds([])
    setLabels([])

    const getPlaylistDataRecursively = (url) => {
      return fetch('/spotify/get-track-ids', {headers: {
        'url': url
      }})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {

        console.log(data)

        setTitles(titles => ([...titles, ...data.title]))
        setArtists(artists => ([...artists, ...data.artist]))
        setFeatures(features => ([...features, ...data.features]))
        setIds(ids => ([...ids, ...data.track_ids]))

        if (data.next_url) {
          const next_url = data.next_url.replace('https://api.spotify.com/v1', '')
          return getPlaylistDataRecursively(next_url)
        } else {
          return fetch('/spotify/get-dimension-reduction', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(features)
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            setTSNEfeatures(data)
          })
        }
      })
    }

    return getPlaylistDataRecursively(`/playlists/${playlistId}/tracks/?offset=0&limit=100`)
      .then(() => {
        hideLoading()
      });
  }
```

The problem is that `fetch('/spotify/get-dimension-reduction' ... )` is ran before `getPlaylistDataRecursively` is done filling the `features` state. How can I tackle this issue?

Comment: Pass the features to `getPlaylistDataRecursively`?

Comment: Why "wait" for anything? You know when you're run out of data, use that signal to trigger the code path that needs to happen once you have all the data. "if more, recurse, if not, run this.andNowProcessAllOfThis()" should work fine?

Comment: there is the option of useEffect also,wrapp the whole function inside it, give the dependency arrays of the states that should be updated, it will trigger when some state has been updated, you can place the function also inside some conditions if you know the previous values of the states, sth like: if state.one !== xvalue

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I revised my code, the problem remains though. 'features' is empty when the else block is executed.

Comment: I'm not going to guess at what all your undocumented code does, though: turn this into a [mcve], and include what `setFeatures` does (with everything else removed, because you don't need to show the same thing happening 8 times, once is both necessary and sufficient).

Comment: Makes sense. This is a snippet of my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-hypatia-6701w?file=/src/App.js. I can't include the backend but I explained what is being returned by a call with comments. Hope that works for you, since it's not a working snippet for this reason. Otherwise I'll make it work.